# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: object is not a constructor(…) in ionic2

Tags: ionic2, es6-shim

While using ionic2 running basic app also it's giving error like this: **Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: object is not a constructor(…)** in ionic2.

---

create new app: ionic start appname tutorial --v2

running app: ionic serve

My system Specifications:

Ubuntu :14.04 (64bit)

Chrome :Version 49.0.2623.87 (64-bit)

Node : v5.6.0

npm : v3.6.0

[image]

Comment: its not a ionic2 problem, its a es6-shim one :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see [here](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/5175). It shows up with a particular Chrome Canary version, and it seems due to es6-shim. It has been reported to have been fixed in [es6-shim v0.34](https://github.com/paulmillr/es6-shim/releases/tag/0.34.4). Or you can switch to core-js shim, as mentioned [here](https://github.com/blacksonic/angular2-es6-starter/issues/1#issuecomment-196838211).

But if you're using some library (like Ionic) that depends on a particular es6-shim version, I guess you'd wait for library update.

Comment: BTW next time throw a Google search with (parts of) error message and see what comes out.

Comment: Nice to see my repo in the answer as a solution :)

Comment: to downvoters: please allow me to understand what's wrong in the answer. TA

Comment: @superjos I have upgraded to `shim 0.35` but I still see the error, can you help me on this please.. my project is on https://github.com/globalquran/mobile-app

Comment: Just to be on the safe side, have you tried deleting `es6-shim` directory under `node_modules`, then running `npm install` again?

Comment: It seems in Canary 51 the issue gets fixed? See the discussion in the first link of this answer so hard to say if this is because of es6-shim or the browser.